# Firebase notification work for both background and foreground

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I am working with a web app and intend to use firebase to push notification. So far, I have managed to push a notification in background while not viewing web-app and receive the notify, display it in foreground while viewing. The problem is that they don't work together. I want to received notification from both side. A pop up corner notify and when I open my web, the notify would be there also. Right now, I'm using `AngularFireMessaging.messages.subcribe` to get the notify and then display it.